# Database changes not reflecting after Rake and Migrate commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working very first time on Rails Application. I am using Rails 4. As per tutorials and books I used `Rails migrate` command to generate initial schema. After that I called `rake db:migrate`. The message says table created but when I go to `db/development.sqlite3` I find no table at all.

Following is the code of Migration File

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :summary
      t.integer :total_impacts #added later but does not reflect in db
      t.integer :current_status #added later but does not reflect in db
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

What steps am I missing?

Comment: Did you mean something like: `rails g migration CreateFirstTest` then `rake db:migrate`. I am not sure how it didn't reflect changes in database. One way to assure is to check the migration file which has been created by `rails g migration ...` command. Does that file have something like: `create_table :first_tests do |t| ...`?

Comment: @Surya I updated the question for better understanding

Comment: Since you've just begin you can try: `rake db:drop` then `rake db:create` and then `rake db:migrate` to see if this works. But please never do this when your project grows, as it'll drop the db with the all data in it.

Comment: @Surya I rather called `db:schema:load` and it worked

Comment: Cool, glad it worked out for you.

Comment: For `:total_impacts` and `:current_status` you specified `added later but does not reflect in db`.

Have you runned the migration first, then edit it and try running it again?

Comment: @fab yes I edit later

Answer (score 0):

Since I am on early stages of Database I rather called  `db:schema:load` after making changes in `schema.rb` file.

I guess `add_column` should work too but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments, I assume that the table was successfully created but that it's only a problem with the `:total_impacts` and `:current_status` columns.

---

If you run a migration once, the database knows that it's already been through it and won't run it again unless specified explicitly (`rake db:migrate VERSION=...`).

So if you write a migration, run it, then update it and try to run it again, the stuff you've just added (like a new column) won't appear in your database (because the migration has already been run in the database point of view).

If you realize after running the migration that you forgot some things, you have two options:

- You can write another migration for the things you want to add/delete and run it. (Easy stuff).
- You can rollback the migration (play the `down` part), edit it and run it again (play the `up` part). This one can be a bit more tricky depending on when you realize your mistake (has some data related to that migration already been added? etc).